# Mark message as already read from iPhone lock screen

Tags: iphone, sms

Most messages(SMS) can be known to be useless from iPhone lock screen, then you need to unlock screen->go to message->(possibly go out of another conversation)->go into that conversation or mark it as already use->go back to all messages.

How to mark the useless message as already read on the lock screen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS 15 there is no "View" option on swipe left, but you can achieve the same with a long press on the message.

Then click outside the window to close the message, it will be marked as viewed.

Comment: More recent answer

Comment: One answer per version...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this.

When receiving a message, swipe left on the notification, you will be presented with the screen below:

[image]

Then click view, this will open the message on the lock screen. Then click anywhere on the screen to close the box. This marks the message as *read*.