# How to delete message from iPhone lock screen?

Tags: ios, messages, notifications, sms, screen-lock

When a SMS come in, it is shown on the lock screen with part of its content shown. If it is useless, how to delete the message directly from the lock screen without unlock the phone?

There are ways to clear the message notification on the lock screen without unlocking the phone like [Mark message as already read from iPhone lock screen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/390017/mark-message-as-already-read-from-iphone-lock-screen), but not to delete the message, clearing the notification doesn't delete the message.

Online search result are complaints about not having this feature and using 3rd party software.

Does iOS really not support this feature?

Answer (score 1):

No, iOS really doesn’t have this feature. You can only delete messages from the notification area of your Lock Screen, but deleting something without unlocking the phone is not possible. It is the same with photos you take while your phone is locked, and then delete them, while it is still locked, they still show up in your gallery, although they are already in the bin folder. As there is nothing like this for messages, deleting them from your Lock Screen is a feature anybody could use, not only the owner, so it is not supported.